# SQL return latest data from each date

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample table

| id | id_sequence | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-06-27 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-06-27 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-06-27 |
| 4 | 2 | 2022-06-27 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022-06-27 |
| 6 | 1 | 2022-06-28 |
| 7 | 1 | 2022-06-28 |
| 8 | 2 | 2022-06-28 |
| 9 | 2 | 2022-06-28 |

Expected Output

| id | id_sequence | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 2022-06-27 |
| 5 | 2 | 2022-06-27 |
| 7 | 1 | 2022-06-28 |
| 9 | 2 | 2022-06-28 |

how can I make a query to get latest data on every date in MySql. tried to use MAX(id) for the id_sequence but it does not return a correct value since the expected output will take only highest id of every sequence and the output will only display distinct data of id_sequence 1,2 at date 2022-06-28.

Comment: what version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make sure dates are taken distinctively, you need to add it inside the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, 
       id_sequence,
       date_
FROM tab
GROUP BY id_sequence,
         date_
ORDER BY id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6DGoxZo9dxuvLhjEeK6Zg5/0).